# How to incorporate phantomJS for this selenium code

Tags: browser-automation

A sample of this which is converted from selenium IDE to C#. This is not exactly what it is after converted to run on Visual studio. But the regression tests made change sometimes and  would like to add phantomjs to do headless whenever there is a built change.How to add phantomJS in this instance to ensure that there are no problems? Something simple and yet manageable by most non devs?

```
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("region1")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("region3")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.row.modal-footer-offset > button.btn.btn-warning")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.row.modal-footer-offset > button.btn.btn-primary")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("filter-submit")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Next')])[2]")).Click();
        // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [captureEntirePageScreenshot | c:/test/contractDetails2.png | ]]
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Search by Contract")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("item-clear")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("contractSearch")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("contractSearch")).SendKeys("d");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("filter-submit")).Click();
```

Comment: PhantomJS works EXACTLY like any other browser - that's the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of your `driver` reference.  Instantiate it as a `GhostDriver` or `PhantomJSDriver`

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

// Use this as you would any other browser
```

Whichever implementation of WebDriver you choose, whether it be ChromeDriver, FirefoxDriver, SafariDriver...  Once you have that `driver` reference, the way to use it is exactly the same.